# Проклятие размерности

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Подскажите где можно почитать про сабж, в основном интересует когда встречается (для программистов) и как бороться.

Comment: Меня тоже интересует, никогда не встречал такого понятия. Это связано с программированием или научной фантастикой?

Comment: @VladD это судя по всему связано  [вот с чем][1]

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: @DreamChild: А, понял, спасибо.

@cyberdream: думаю, это проблема не касается не программистов, а статистиков. Дело программиста — обрабатывать данные, а дело статистиков — поставлять эти данные программистам и получать от них ответ, что анализ 2^100 выборок займёт 2^70 лет.

Comment: @VladD ну проблемы, вызванные комбинаторным взрывом, как правило касаются именно программистов.

Comment: @alexlz: тут вопрос алгоритмов, насколько я понимаю. «Комбинаторный взрыв» == много данных для обработки, так что проблема на стороне, которая ставит задачу. Программист всего лишь кодирует предложенный алгоритм обработки данных, разве нет?

Comment: @VladD

      И опять пошла морока про коварный зарубеж.

Или, абстрагируясь от Высоцкого, опять приходим к вопросу "что есть программист"...

Comment: @alexlz: ну да :-) Я знаю, что во многих проектах программист одновременно и _граф. дизайнер_ (придумывает интерфейс, рисует иконки и скины), и _product manager_ (придумывает фичи и поведение), и _сэйлс_ (ведёт переговоры с заказчиком). Но это — дополнительные задания, не имеющие отношения к должности программиста. Так же, как мне кажется, и алгоритмы: их должен придумывать _математик_ и обсуждать с _архитектором_.

Comment: @VladD, у нас тут в ходу анекдоты про «ну вы же программисты! что ж вы, чайник отремонтировать не можете?» и «нужен сильный программист. надо шкаф передвинуть».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: ну, по большому счёту на просьбу придумать статистический алгоритм, нарисовать иконки, передвинуть шкаф, подмести коридор и всё такое программист должен отвечать вежливым _fuck off_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для программистов в основном встречается когда применяют [динамическое программирование](http://www.math.mrsu.ru/text/courses/method/dinamicheskoe_programmirovanie1.htm)

Comment: Странное утверждение. Подтверждения есть?

Comment: вы по ссылке вообще текст читали? Ричард Беллман американский математик, один из ведущих специалистов в области математики и вычислительной техники утверждает: "Главным недостатком метода (речь идет о динамическом программировании) является, говоря словами Беллмана, «проклятие размерности» – его сложность катастрофически возрастает с увеличением размерности задачи."

Comment: @wefwefgwe О горе мне! Я не прочитал слова Беллмана! Судьба меня за это сильно накажет.

А что, в других задачах такие проблемы не возникают? Или возникают, но реже?

А насчёт Беллмана: 

     Профессор, в Вы Ваньку Рыжего знаете? А Петьку Рваного? Нет? А чего же своими пугаете?

Comment: @alexlz что за истерия?

Comment: @wefwefgwe так это, я не прочитал слова Беллмана, значит я безнадёжен.

Comment: Вы не удосужились вообще прочитать мой ответ внимательно, так что да - безнадежны.